# What should a page's minimum word count be in order to be effectively indexed?

Tags: seo, content

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Ideal word count per web page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24083/ideal-word-count-per-web-page)

I'm seeding a new site with hundreds of (high quality) posts, but since I am paying per word written, I'm wondering if anybody in the community has any anecdotal evidence as to how many words of content there should now be for a page to be counted just the same as a 700 word+ post, for example?

I know there are always examples of pages ranking well with, for instance, 50 words or less of content, but does anyone have any strong evidence on what the minimum count should be, or has anyone read anything very informative in regards to this issue?

Comment: Have you had a look at http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24083/ideal-word-count-per-web-page ?

Comment: If you're shooting for the bare minimum, then they're probably not gonna be very good posts. If you're not shooting for the bare minimum and are instead shooting for quality, then you don't need to worry about the minimum indexed word count. A good article will have enough content to be indexed by major search engines, and you won't gain any competitive advantage publishing a 600 word article versus a 700 word article. That's not how people judge content quality, so that's not how search engines judge quality either. Just set a reasonable range and let your writers do their job.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no minimum to be indexed. There are lots of pages indexed that contain just a few words and a video or image/photo. Being ranked well is a whole different story. A page can contain very little physical content and rank well thanks to the incoming links it attracts. As always it is about quality not quantity.

Answer (score -1):

As per google webmasters tools minimum word count should be 250 words per page. [Refer these discussion](http://groups.google.com/a/googleproductforums.com/forum/#!category-topic/webmasters/crawling-indexing--ranking/cc1kxq6rLhw)

Comment: It's unclear why you think this answers anything; the 250 you cite from that thread is part of the *question*.