# What is actually meant by "quality content" for SEO?

Tags: content

I have read thousands time "quality content is the key" or "write quality content" to be first page on Google.

But, what is actually meant by "quality content"?

Ex Title : "Top 10 Internet Marketing Forums"

If I need to write article about above topic how should I determine what is the word count and how to maintain the quality?

Comment: There is no target for word count.  See: [What should be the word count of an article for better ranking in 2014?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/60068/what-should-be-the-word-count-of-an-article-for-better-ranking-in-2014) and [Ideal word count per web page?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/24083/ideal-word-count-per-web-page) and [Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google)  "Quality content" certainly does not mean "has the right word count"

Comment: Your example title, and I do realize it is just an example, would be an indication of poor content. It is *me too*  content that exists everywhere, becomes out dated, is designed only for traffic, does not solve a specific problem, is not quotable, is in a highly competitive space, provides no expertise, etc. I could go on and on. Quality content is not the same 'ole same 'ole crapola that you see everywhere but something of real substance. Cheers!!

Comment: I have wasted more than 40 minutes here to write answer, and then I delete it. Because google is machine, it doesn't understand best vs good, reality vs scam, truth vs myth. They still heavily depend on links. No matter how great blog post you've write, you can't beat forbes blog post, I know you've good UX, good content then forbes but they've so many backlinks, which google can't ignore it. Google doesn't compare only your two websites, there're millions, and hence they use more than 200+ signals. So make quality content for users, they will share/link and will help you to grow your site.

Comment: @Goyllo is making a perfectly valid point. Quality content is paramount, no question, however, PageRank in the form of back links is still the premium factor that Google uses to determine the value of content. This can only be set aside with other factors such as determining a good semantics match between the content and search query. Short search queries reduce SERP link quality and tends to lean toward content with more links. As most people make simple queries first, content that is found leans toward content with more links and links are votes that indicate some level of quality.

Comment: That said, high quality content should always be produced. First, quality content is shared more often and linked to organically more often. Second, user satisfaction becomes paramount in retaining user attention and retention. Also remember that powerhouse sites such as Forbes can also be rejected by users. I, for one, avoid that site. Why? Because it is slow and annoying. I prefer to visit sites with real information from real experts and not just some article posted by a journalist that is often limited in scope and parrots what every other journalist has written. Cheers!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Quality Content:**

It means the content which is unique and which addresses the user needs correctly.

A content which is easy to read and which is engaging.

A quality content may not just be flat text but an appropriate combination of text, images, videos etc.

A quality content could also ben an illustration which could be problem-solving.

**Length**: The length of the content isn't the deciding factor for quality content. But just make sure it's not too short.

Worth reading recent discussion:
[Is word count a large ranking factor for Google?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/106761/is-word-count-a-large-ranking-factor-for-google)

Comment: I would add:  appropriate reading level for the audience, attractive look, and something done better than the competitors.   Also, avoid low quality such as: plagiarism, bad spelling and grammar, poor layout, or excessive ads.

Comment: I would add that on every page, there has to be at least some sort of text about the topic on the page because a page that shows only an image and/or special multimedia such as flash by itself wouldn't help those (such as the blind) who require screen readers to describe the page to them.